What can we do when DSolve gives an ugly result?
I obtain an ugly result when I solve an ODE using DSolve in MMA 13.3. The ODE is
DSolve[2 r^3 b^2 k[r] - 2 r^3 k[r]^3 + (a^2 + r^4 b^2) k'[r] == 0, k[r], r] // Simplify

The result is

It looks so ugly. I tried to solve this ODE using Maple. The result is

I know the two results are the same essentially. However, I want to know whether MMA can give a similar form to Maple's for this ODE.

It really depends which solver was used to solve an ode. This can affect the final form.
Maple solved this as Bernoulli ode.
ode:=2*r^3*b^2*k(r) - 2*r^3*k(r)^3 + (a^2 + r^4*b^2)*diff(k(r),r)=0;
infolevel[dsolve]:=5;
sol:=dsolve(ode)

Methods for first order ODEs:
--- Trying classification methods ---
trying a quadrature
trying 1st order linear
trying Bernoulli
<- Bernoulli successful


Mathematica must have picked different solver. May be as Exact ode or Lie symmetry.
Final form that results can be sensitive to which solver was used (even though with algebraic manipulations one should be able to convert all final forms to same form).
An ode sometimes can be solved in many different ways and it depends how the software decides which method to use.
To obtain the same exact solution as Maple, we simply solve it as Bernoulli in Mathematica, using standard Bernoulli change of variables.
ode = 2 r^3 b^2 k[r] - 2 r^3 k[r]^3 + (a^2 + r^4 b^2) k'[r] == 0
(* convert to Bernoulli *)
DSolveChangeVariables[Inactive[DSolve][ode, k[r], r], u, r,  k[r] == 1/Sqrt[u[r]]]


(*solve*)
solU=Activate[%]


(*convert back to original k[r]*)
solK = solU[[1, 1]] /. u[r] -> 1/k[r]^2


solK/.Rule->Equal


Solve[%,k[r]]


Which is exactly what Maple gave.

deq = 2*r^3*b^2*k[r] - 2*r^3*k[r]^3 + (a^2 + r^4*b^2)*k'[r] == 0

sol = Simplify[DSolve[deq, k[r], r]]

k[r_] = k[r] /. sol[[2]]

Combine constants, assuming b is a constant.
k[r_] = k[r] /. {E^(b^2 C[1]) -> -I c, E^(2 b^2 C[1]) -> (-I c)^2}
(* (b c)/Sqrt[a^2 + b^2 r^4 + c^2] *)

deq // Simplify
(* True *)

Is that simple enough for you?
